# Does Rscript change LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Tags: linux, r, fortran, ld, intel-mkl

I am running a version of `R` (which was not compiled with intel parallel studio) and am attempting to load an intel compiled shared `Fortran` library that I compiled myself. In the script I am using to run, I include the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and then use `Rscript` to run the `R` script (which calls `dyn.load("My_Fortran.so")`, compiled using ifort and mkl).

When I run the script, however, it fails with `Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_avx.so or libmkl_def.so`. Is it possible that `Rscript` undoes my setting of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? If not, is it possible that since this version of R was not compiled with intel parallel studio, that it cannot load the shared libraries?

Here is how I am running the R script and loading the path:

```
#!/bin/bash
module load R/3.1.0
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/intel_parallel_studio/xe_2015_u3/install/mkl/lib/intel64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
Rscript myRscript.r
```

The R script fails with:

```
Running R code
Attempting to load Fortran compiled shared library ... Done!
Calling Fortran subroutine from within R ... 
MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_avx.so or libmkl_def.so
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at the shell script source code of both `R` and `Rscript`.

In general such PATH settings (for executables as well as shared libraries) are generally only *added to* and not overwritten.  So you may have another problem.

Can you edit `/etc/ld.so.conf` ?

*Edit* Also consider setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` *before* you do `module load R/3.1.0`.